# Hibernate - delete row based on entered ID...how?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to delete row with ID, which is displaying on textfield, and I got error: "could not extract ResultSet". I tried to do it in two ways but none of them is working... how can I do it properly?

first way:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("clinic");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    Patient patient = new Patient();
    patient.setPID(infoPIDField.getText());

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Patient WHERE idpatient = :idpatient", Patient.class);
    query.setParameter("idpatient", patient.getPID());

    patient = (Patient) query.getResultList().get(1);

    entityManager.remove(patient);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();


    entityManager.close();
    entityManagerFactory.close();
```

second way (error: update/delete queries cannot be typed):

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("clinic");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    Patient patient = new Patient();
    patient.setPID(infoPIDField.getText());

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE Patient WHERE idpatient = :idpatient", Patient.class);
    query.setParameter("idpatient", patient.getPID());

    int result = query.executeUpdate();


    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();


    entityManager.close();
    entityManagerFactory.close();
```

Patient:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
public class Patient {

@Id
public String PID;

public String getPID() {
    return PID;
}
public void setPID(String pID) {
    PID = pID;
```

Comment: In your queries you are referencing idpatient and your @Id roperty of Patient is PID: so in queries you are referncing non-existing property. Another problem name PID is not compliant with default Hibernate behaviour — inside of query that is actually pID - case sensitive. (and that could be also a source of problems )

Comment: And don't forget to flush() your modifications prior to finishing transaction, could be your environment is not autoflushing.

Comment: something off topic: are you sure you want to manage transaction that manually?  It is usually not a good idea to do so, especially if your application become more complicated

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 patient = (Patient) query.getResultList().get(1);
```

should be

```
 patient = (Patient) query.getResultList().get(0);
```

assuming that there should only be one row returned based upon a id lookup.

Even better to check how many rows are returned, may be zero.

Answer (score 0):

The first way should be

```
patient = (Patient) query.getResultList.get(0);
```

The second way should be:

```
 Query query = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE Patient as p WHERE p.idpatient = :idpatient");
```

Because you are using HQL and it works as Java Objects, you have to reference the attribute idpatient throught the Patient object.

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply deleting an entity by ID, I don't think first way is the way to go as you are selecting the entity unnecessarily.

Second way is less portable.  Iirc, bulk delete/update in HQL/JPQL is only available in later version of JPA/Hibernate, and such kind of bulk delete/update may trigger flush and invalidation/refresh of first level cache (cannot remember very clearly if it is true for the first-level cache point though :P )

There are other way to do delete by ID with less side-effect:

(code may be wrong, just for demonstrating idea)

```
Long id = whateverWayYouGetTheId();
Patient patientToBeDeleted = entityManager.getReference(Patient.class, id);
entityManager.remove(patientToBeDeleted);
```